# Greedy Coin Change Time Complexity

Tags: time-complexity, greedy, coin-change

I'm trying to figure out the time complexity of a greedy coin changing algorithm. (I understand Dynamic Programming approach is better for this problem but I did that already). I'm not sure how to go about doing the `while` loop, but I do get the `for` loop.

I have the following where `D[1...m]` is how many denominations there are (which always includes a 1), and where `n` is how much you need to make change for.

This is my algorithm:

```
CoinChangeGreedy(D[1...m], n)
    numCoins = 0
    for i = m to 1
        while n ≥ D[i]
            n -= D[i]
            numCoins += 1
    return numCoins
```

Comment: `I understand DP is better`  What is DP in this context?

Comment: @Amy Dynamic programming I'd guess?

Comment: Yes, DP was dynamic programming. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let look at the edge cases.

At the worse case `D` include only 1 element (when `m=1`) then you will loop `n` times in the while loop -> the complexity is O(n).

If `m>>n` (`m` is a lot bigger then `n`, so `D` has a lot of element whom bigger then `n`) then you will loop on all `m` element till you get samller one then `n` (most work will be on the for-loop part) -> then it O(m).

Button line: **O(max(m,n))**

Hope that helps!

Comment: I guess I don't understand how you loop `n` times when n is decremented by a value that is dependent in the denominations `D[1...m]` array.

Comment: For the complexity I looked at the worse case - if `m=1` then it will loop `n` times (try to run example). Of course if `m` bigger then the complexity decrease.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. What would the best-case be then?

Comment: @dgfrey102790 O(1) when `m=n`. I guess average case will be little bit more then `n/m` when `m<n`

Comment: Would it be wrong to say `O(m + n)` instead of `O(max(m, n))`?

Comment: If we limit denominations to integers then the smallest possible denomination is `m`, and I think we can get a tighter bound from that and say `O(m + n / m)`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help. I changed around the algorithm I had to something I could easily calculate the time complexity for. Here's what I changed it to:

```
CoinChangeGreedy(D[1...m], n)
    numCoins = 0
    for i = m to 1
        if n/D[i] ≥ 1
            numCoins = numCoins + (n/D[i])
            n = n - [(n/D[i]) * D[i]]
    return numCoins
```

Where I calculated this to have worst-case = best-case `\in` `\Theta(m)`